# When will scenario tests be available in JUnit 5?

Tags: junit5

At a conference (JavaForum Stuttgart 2016) they said that JUnit 5 will include a feature to support scenario tests: http://2016.java-forum-stuttgart.de/de/Abstracts+Slot+1.html#art476

They said that TestNG has this feature already, but I don't know TestNG, so I don't know how that looks like.

I guess that would be something like in Allure with @Step annotations and the ability to name each step.

Is that still planned to implement before the initial version of JUnit 5 is released (general availability version)?

If it is not planned anymore to include into JUnit 5, then what alternative would you suggest?

Comment: My German's not good enough to read that page, but it sounds like Cucumber would do the job.

Comment: I don't really like Cucumber, which is why I hope that they will have a scenario feature in JUnit 5. But yes, that would be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

It is still planned, see [issue #48](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/48). It is slated for [Milestone 5](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/milestone/8), which is scheduled for December 30th. Note that the team already pushed back a couple of milestones, which makes it likely that this will not be the actual release date.