# Cannot find @ScenarioTest

Tags: java, eclipse, junit5

I added in Eclipse dependency for JUnit 5:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But when I compile the maven project I get multiple errors like this:

```
    Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/Documents/rest_api/src/test/java/org/rest/api/poc/DatabaseFeaturesBitStringTest.java:[14,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class ScenarioTest
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue? What is the proper way to import @ScenarioTest?

Comment: Have you imported the class?

Comment: No, I can't find which class to import.

Comment: Where have you find such Annotation?

Comment: https://jochenchrist.github.io/hello-junit5/#/13

Comment: As i can see it is not implemented yet: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-workshop/blob/master/slides/06_roadmap/roadmap.md

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953375/when-will-scenario-tests-be-available-in-junit-5

Comment: It is planned for 5.4 now: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/48

Comment: Is there any other way to run JUnit tests in strict order?

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate why you need to run tests in a certain order?

Answer (score 1):

Scenario tests are planned for 5.4. See details at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/48